# Laravel: What if you don't commit or rollback the transaction you started manually?

Tags: php, laravel, transactions

I recently started working with PHP/Laravel (I have been working with Java for 15+ years). I noticed this code in the codebase:

```
public function doSomeStuffInDb() {
  DB::beginTransaction();
  // Some db calls here
  DB::commit();
}
```

I already found in the documentation that the proper way to do it is to use `DB::transaction` with a closure containing the db calls.

But I wonder what happens when there is an exception calling the database before the `DB::commit()` call? I assume nothing will be stored in the db since you don't commit, but can it have further consequences (db row locks?)? Will the transaction be aborted when leaving the function?

Comment: have you found any answers ?

Answer (score 2):

Any transaction that haven't been committed or rolledback potentially have the same dangers of dirty reads, non-repeatable reads, phantom reads and all the other considerations you also would have implementing in java.

Meaning - even though the locking is done at a row level, with queries run as nonlocking consistent reads, you end up with a lot of further consequences. Lock's are handled depending on your database setup, some time them out, some leave them be.

Comment: We are using MySQL if that matters